# Ошибка при записи в поле типа string объекта строки длиннее 15 символов

Tags: c++, строки, объекты, память

Существуют классы Student, Semester, Subject (в студенте есть массив объектов семестров, а в семестре массив объектов класса предмет), а также меню, где пользователь управляет данными студентов.
Объекты класса Student хранятся в двусвязном списке построенном по такой структуре:

```cpp
struct BothWayList{

    BothWayList(BothWayList *pPrevious, BothWayList *pNext, Student* value) {

        this->id = ++BothWayList::count;
        this->previous = pPrevious;
        this->next = pNext;
        this->value = value;
    }

    int id;
    BothWayList* previous;
    BothWayList* next;
    Student* value;

    static int count;
    static BothWayList* pStart;

};
```

Внутри меню осуществляется поиск нужного элемента списка, после чего по выбору пользователя (нас интересует case 1), происходит запуск метода найденного студента:

```cpp
if (foundStudent != nullptr){
                        cout << "What would you like to with found student:"
                            << endl << "1. Edit"
                            << endl << "2. Delete"
                            << endl << "3. Nothing"
                            << endl;
                        cin >> choiceStr2;
                        choice2 = stoi(choiceStr2);

                        switch(choice2){
                            case 1: { foundStudent->value->editInfo(); break; }
                            case 2: { deleteStudent(foundStudent); break; }
                            case 3: {break;}
                            default: {cout << "ERROR! Unknown menu item, skipping!" << endl;}
                        }
                    }
```

В методе editInfo происходит перебор по всем полям с вопросами пользователю, что он хочет менять, и когда дело доходит до изменения семестров, даётся возможность добавить новый предмет в этот семестр (именно это нас и интересует, поэтому часть кода, не относящегося к делу обрезана):

```cpp
                cout << "Do you want to edit this semester? (Y/N):" << endl;
                cin >> wannaEdit;
                if (wannaEdit == "Y" || wannaEdit == "y") {
                    string subjectStr;
                    while (true) {
                        cout
                                << "Enter subject that you want to change or enter \"exit\" to exit or enter \"DELETE\" to delete this semester or \"addnew\" to add new subject:"
                                << endl;
                        cin.get();
                        getline(cin, subjectStr);
                        if (subjectStr == "addnew") {
                            semester.addSubject();
                            break;
                        }
```

Далее мы переходим к методу уже семестра addSubject:

```cpp
int Semester::addSubject(){
    for (auto & subject : subjects){
        if (!subject.is_active()){
            subject.is_active(true);

            string subjName;
            cout << "Enter name of subject:" << endl;
            if (cin.get() != '\n')
                cin.unget();
            getline(cin, subjName);
            subject.setName(subjName);
            cout << "You've just successfully added " << subjName << " subject" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "You can't add subject in this semester, because it is fully loaded (max. number of subjects in one semester - 10)" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

И отсюда, наконец, переходим к тому самому месту, где происходит непонятная (по крайней мере для меня) дичь, - в метод setName объекта класса subject (он, не удивительно, весьма прост):

```cpp
int Subject::setName(const string& subjName) {
    this->name = subjName;
    return 0;
}
```

поле name, разумеется, - string.
Пробелма в том, что если пользователь на моменте ввода имени нового предмета введёт, скажем, "Programming languages", то программа завершится с ошибкой, а дебаггер будет кидаться подобными фекалиями: "Exception: Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x77d487: Access violation reading location 0x005d5724". Я выполнял вхождение в системные функции в процессе дебагга, и выяснилось, что ошибка возникает в системном файле xmemory в функции _Orphan_all(). А именно, программа пытается обратиться к _Myproxy, по адресу, к которому не может получить доуступ:
[image: Ошибка в _Orphan_all()]

При всём этом, стоит ввести в поле имени что-то покороче, то проблем не возникает. Опытном путём удалось установить, что при 15-символьном имени всё отрабатывает как нужно, а уже при 16 символах всё идёт к чёрту. И при этом именно такую capacity (15) указывает дебаггер для `this` в системном операторе `basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& _Right)` для класса `_String_val` в файле xstring:
[image: capacity]

А самое интересное - если тоже самое делать просто из main'а, вроде такого:

```cpp
auto* student1 = new Student(
            "Alekseev",
            "Ivan",
            "Valerievich",
            {16, 3, 1911},
            2020,
            "IT",
            "KB-3",
            "INBO-5-19",
            "19B6141",
            Male
    );

(*student1)++; // adding new semester
string subjName;
getline(cin, subjName);
student1->getSemester(1)->addSubject(subjName);
student1->printInfo();
```

Мы получаем совершенно нормальную картину:
[image: Нормальная работа]

И даже при использовании того же метода editInfo() получаем аналогичный результат:
[image: Тоже нормальная работа]

Так что есть подозрение, что дело именно в списке BothWayList, собственно поэтому я  в начале так подробно и описал полный путь до ошибки, начиная аж с создания списка по этой структуре.

Что с этим делать и как это понимать я не сильно представляю, поэтому прошу объяснить достаточно подробно причины происходящего и, желательно, способы устранения этого чуда. Спасибо.

Comment: std::string использует small string optimisation, маленькие строки хранятся непосредственно в теле класса, большие строки требуют выделения динамической памяти. Это причина, по которой проблема не возникает в случае малых строк. Но это не потому, что ошибки при этом нет, просто в вашем случае не происходит критических ошибок обращения к памяти.

Comment: @Ariox, То есть мне нужно заменить`this->name = subjName;` на `this->name = new string(subjName);` в методе Subject::setName?

Comment: нет, это значит, что у вас где-то некорректное обращение к памяти так, что сама строка оказывается в блоке выделенной памяти, но ее конструктор не вызван. Наиболее вероятная причина - где-то проблема с обращением по индексу. Попробуйте везде, где есть обращение по индексу расставить assert с проверкой на выход за пределы массива. .

Что касается new, в хорошем коде его вообще не должно быть. В большинстве случаев объекты создаются в теле класса или на стеке, или же в vector. Если нужны графовые структуры - есть unique_ptr и shared_ptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что проблема была только в том случае, если данные в эти строки загружались из файла, так что пришлось переделать сохранение таким образом, чтобы в файл записывалась не сама строка, а её c_str().  Это исправило ситуацию.